# Tic Tac Toe: Infinite winning after resetting game

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I'm recreating the classic Tic Tac Toe using HTML, CSS, and JS.

I've got the game to run successfully for a single match but functionality seems to have some errors after creating a New Game option. After clicking new game, the winner message will pop up every time a player marks a square.

The game-checking algorithm is inside of the gameBoard variable and named checkWin. It's called inside of displayController after updating the view.

**Pictures showing issue:**

[image: )]
Working normally aside from winning message popping up before showing final X placement (bottom-left)

[image]
**ISSUE:** After clicking new-game, I click a single square and the winning message pops up.

```js
let counter = 0;
let gameBoard = (function() {
  // 'use strict';

  let Board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

  let winningCombinations = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ]

  // has array 
  return {
    Board: Board,
    clickSquare: function(player) {
      document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
          // console.log(item.id.replace('_',''));
          player.markSquare(item.id.replace('_', ''));
        })
      });
    },
    checkWin: function() {
      return winningCombinations.some(combination => {
        return combination.every(index => {
          return Board[index] === "X"
        }) || combination.every(index => {
          return Board[index] === "O"
        })
      })
    }
  }
})();



let displayController = (function() {
  'use strict';

  function updateView(square) {
    console.log(square);
    document.querySelector("#_" + square).textContent = gameBoard.Board[square];
    if (gameBoard.checkWin() && counter % 2 === 0) {
      alert("Player One Wins!");
    } else if (gameBoard.checkWin() && counter % 2 !== 0) {
      alert("Player Two Wins!");
    } else if (counter == 8) {
      alert("TIE!");
    }
    counter++;
  }
  return {
    updateView: updateView
  }
})();

function createPlayer(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    markSquare(square) {
      if (gameBoard.Board[square] === "") {
        if (counter % 2 === 0) {
          gameBoard.Board[square] = "X";
        } else {
          gameBoard.Board[square] = "O";
        }

        displayController.updateView(square);
      }
    }
  }
}

function gameFlow() {
  let player1 = createPlayer("Phil");
  gameBoard.clickSquare(player1);

  let resetGame = document.querySelector("button");
  resetGame.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
      document.querySelector("#_" + i).textContent = "";
    }
    gameBoard.Board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    counter = 0;
  });

}
gameFlow();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#playerNames {
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

input {
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

td {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TicTac.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1><b>Tic Tac Toe</b></h1>
  <div id="playerNames">
    <input id="pOne" placeholder="Player One" type="text">
    <button>New Game</button>
    <input id="pTwo" placeholder="Player Two" type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="_0"></td>
        <td id="_1"></td>
        <td id="_2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="_3"></td>
        <td id="_4"></td>
        <td id="_5"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="_6"></td>
        <td id="_7"></td>
        <td id="_8"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="TicTac.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `winningCombinations` thing is just lazy. Surely, you can find a better way to check for a win.

Comment: Very helpful feedback. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, but you had two problems.

One is that your weren't adding the `click` event correctly to the "New Game" button. I made a quick edit to make it work, but there's other ways to do it.

The second was that you were assigning a new array to `gameBoard.Board.Board`. I'm not sure why that didn't work, but resetting the current values in the loop you already had does work.

Making those two minor changes seems to get things working. I used `console.log`s to make sure that not only were things running correctly, but also to see the values in the variables. It helped me quickly determine the "Reset" method wasn't being called on the button click as well as confirming that the data wasn't being updated as expected. I've left in those logs so you can see them as examples of how to use them. I also left in the code I commented out to show the few differences, so don't forget to clean all this up.

BTW, there's a few things that could be done a little better, but good job so far. This is really fairly clean and concise while working.

```js
let counter = 0;
let gameBoard = (function() {
    // 'use strict';

    let Board = ["", "", "", "", "","","","",""];

    let winningCombinations = [
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8],
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6]
    ]

    // has array 
    return {
        Board: Board,
        clickSquare: function(player) {
            document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(item => {
                item.addEventListener('click', event => {
                    // console.log(item.id.replace('_',''));
                    player.markSquare(item.id.replace('_',''));
                })
            });       
        },
        checkWin: function() {
        console.log(Board);
            return winningCombinations.some(combination => {
                return combination.every(index => {
                    return Board[index] === "X"
                }) || combination.every(index => {
                    return Board[index] === "O"
            })
        })
        }
    }
})();



let displayController = (function() {
    'use strict';

    function updateView(square) {
            console.log(square);
            document.querySelector("#_"+square).textContent = gameBoard.Board[square];
            if (gameBoard.checkWin() && counter %2 === 0) {
                alert("Player One Wins!");
            }
            else if (gameBoard.checkWin() && counter %2 !== 0) {
                alert("Player Two Wins!");
            }
            else if (counter == 8) {
                alert("TIE!");
            }
            counter++;
    }
    return {
        updateView: updateView
    }
})();

function createPlayer(name) {
    return {
        name: name,
        markSquare(square) {
            if (gameBoard.Board[square] === "") {
                if (counter %2 === 0) {
                    gameBoard.Board[square] = "X";
                }
                else {
                    gameBoard.Board[square] = "O";
                }
                
                displayController.updateView(square);
            }
        }
    }
}

function gameFlow() {
    let player1 = createPlayer("Phil");
    gameBoard.clickSquare(player1);

    let resetGame = document.getElementById("resetbutton");
    resetGame.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("reset");
        for (let i =0; i<=8; i++) {
            document.querySelector("#_"+i).textContent="";
            gameBoard.Board[i] = "";
        }
        //gameBoard.Board = ["", "", "", "", "","","","",""];
        counter = 0;
    });
        
}
gameFlow();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;

}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
#playerNames {
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
input {
    width:170px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
}
button {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
table {
    margin: auto;
}
td {
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
}
tr td:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right:2px solid black;
}
tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TicTac.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><b>Tic Tac Toe</b></h1>
    <div id="playerNames">
        <input id="pOne" placeholder="Player One" type="text">
        <button id="resetbutton">New Game</button>
        <input id="pTwo" placeholder="Player Two" type="text">
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="_0"></td>
            <td id="_1"></td>
            <td id="_2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="_3"></td>
            <td id="_4"></td>
            <td id="_5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="_6"></td>
            <td id="_7"></td>
            <td id="_8"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

<script src="TicTac.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I'm also confused why setting gameBoard.Board to a new array of empty strings didn't work but using the loop instead worked.

Comment: @M.Ali, I'm more of an "old school" JS dev, so I don't use the `Let` keyword and don't really know how to use it, but it might be that you need to use it when reassigning the array. It might be something to do with how JS deals with arrays, since they are more of memory pointers that can be locally scoped improperly at times that aren't obvious. I know that happens in React and I don't have those rules committed to memory yet, either.